# How to Read Multiple HTML Tables in R

Tags: r

I am trying to automate the pulling in of and saving to a dataframe of this readHTML function; I am an R newbie and am having trouble figuring out how to write a loop that would automate this function that works if you do it one by one.

```
library('XML')

urls<-c("http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/ATL/","http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BOS/")
theurl<-urls[2] #Pick second link (celtics)

tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
n.rows <- unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
BOS <-tables[[which.max(n.rows)]] 
Team.History<-write.csv(BOS,"Bos.csv")
```

Any and all help would be very appreciated!

Comment: You seem to have figured out how to use `lapply`. Have you considered using those `lapply` skills on your `urls` vector?

Comment: Note that there is no need to assign the result of ‘write.csv‘ to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think this combines the best of both answers (and tidies up a little).

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

stem <- "http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/"
teams <- htmlParse(getURL(stem), asText=T)
teams <- xpathSApply(teams,"//*/a[contains(@href,'/teams/')]", xmlAttrs)[-1]
teams <- gsub("/teams/(.*)/", "\\1", teams)
urls <- paste0(stem, teams)

names(teams) <- NULL   # get rid of the "href" labels
names(urls) <- teams

results <- data.frame()
for(team in teams){
   tables <- readHTMLTable(urls[team])
   n.rows <- unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
   team.results <- tables[[which.max(n.rows)]] 
   write.csv(team.results, file=paste0(team, ".csv"))
   team.results$TeamCode <- team
   results <- rbind(results, team.results)
   rm(team.results, n.rows, tables)
}
rm(stem, team)

write.csv(results, file="AllTeams.csv")
```

Comment: Sean this is masterful.  Thank you!  I hope you use it for your sports scraping pleasure yourself.  Keep in touch on any other sports related scraping stuff you are up to please.  Hit me up on twitter @abresler

Comment: I have been thinking about some Olympics number crunching...but haven't quite found the time. Too much time on SO perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to loop over your urls vector? I'd try something like this:

```
library('XML')

url_base <- "http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/"
teams <- c("ATL", "BOS")

# better still, get the full list of teams as in
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/11804014/1543437

results <- data.frame()
for(team in teams){
   theurl <- paste(url_base, team , sep="/")
   tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
   n.rows <- unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
   team.results <-tables[[which.max(n.rows)]] 
   write.csv(team.results, file=paste0(team, ".csv"))
   team.results$TeamCode <- team
   results <- rbind(results, team.results)
}
write.csv(results, file="AllTeams.csv")
```

Comment: You might also want to bundle all the results into a single file (see update in answer above).